# READ MORE feature on text retrieved in database?

Tags: html

Basically does anyone know how I could retrieve a large amount of text from mySQL and have it in a variable. Then when it is echo'd in the DOM to only show SOME of it and then show the rest of it with a "read more" button.

Comment: How are you communicating with your db?  What backend are you using?  You'll need more than HTML for this...

Comment: PHP, mySQL, Apache. Hope that answers your question haha

Comment: Do you know how to query a database with PHP?

Comment: @WillardSolutions and yes of course I can use PHP or JQuery or vanilla Javascript. I have a basic knowledge of all of them, just don't exactly know to go about this

Comment: Yes, getting the data via PHP is not an issue :) You can assume I have the large passage of text in a php variable :)

Comment: If you want to load it all on the page, put the 'read more' part in a hidden div and show it on a button click.  Or you can fetch the rest of the text via an ajax call.  There are lots of ways to do this - you need to ask a more specific question to get specific help

Comment: @WillardSolutions I'll give you a bit of perspective :) The page is a "Blogs Post" page. In my database I have columns such as Blog Title, Blog Image, Blog Date, Blog Text. The Blog Test field will have the body text which will be large. On the blogs page I'd like to have a relatively small Div for each post, with the title, image and text. However if I show all of the Blog Text the div will be very big. So I'd like to just show some of the Blog Text and when the user clicks the "read more" button. The div expands in height to show the rest of the Blog Text.

Comment: There are literally thousands of tutorials on the Google that can get you started. I suggest your start there, and then use Stackoverflow once you get stuck on a specific question.